# Disable Drag-and-drop text editing in Delphi editor

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Many text editors have a feature which allows you to click-and-drag some text from one part of the file and drop it somewhere else. Can this be disabled in Delphi 7? I searched Delphi 7 > Tools > Editor Options but found no option for this.

Comment: Just stop dragging text around

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: :o) Unfortunately, possibly due to heavy-finger-syndrome, I occasionally drag text by accident (but never deliberately, I don't use or want this feature).

Comment: Since the feature you want does not exist you'll just have to get used to it. Or you could hack the IDE I guess but hardly seems worth it to me.